# Sculpting problems: sculpt.brush_stroke invert doesn't work when assigning to Alt key. Can't assign Ctrl to mask brush. Anyone know why? Thanks!

Tags: sculpting, keymap

Like the title say. I'm trying to replicate the zbrush way in blender, but when assigning Alt key to sculpt.brush_stroke it doesnt work. The interface still move when pressing Alt and doesnt carve/invert my brush stroke.

Also, I don't know why I cannot assign the Ctrl key to the mask brush. It just doesnt work. Anyone know some workaround or is it just impossible? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: If you want to use the Alt key for something other than emulating a three button mouse but with three button mouse emulation still turned on, you need to assign a different key to that first.

Comment: Yes, it's probably the case that the key that the keymap for ALT is set at like 3D View (Global) or something and that is overriding whatever changes you're making in the Sculpt Mode keymap.

Comment: Having worked between Blender and ZBrush i have found it easier to modify ZBrush/ My Tablet settings to work like Blender rather than the other way around.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer! Where do you go to make the change? I use blender 3.3 and and I don't know where to go to change the button. In some thread I saw people who had a dropbown menu to change the key that was assigned to their <<emulate 3 mouse buttons>> but in my interface this option isnt here.